# How to copy the value of Dropdownlist, subtract a value (default is 0) and calculate the sum, just by clicking on the Dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, calculation

Tools used: Asp.net core 5.0, Visual studio 2019

I want to copy the value from DropdownList into textbox2, textbox1 is the quantity (default is 1), 
on textbox3 is the value to be subtracted (default is 0) and 
on textbox4 calculate the sum, just by selecting the value on the DropdownList? 
textbox4 = (textbox1 * textbox2) - textbox3;
Is there a way to do it in C# or Javascript?

This is the Create page that i'm using.

```
        <div class="form-group" hidden>
            <input asp-for="Rows.Qty" class="form-control" value="1" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Rows.Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Price" id="ReadPrice" name="ReadPrice" >
            </select>
            <input asp-for="Rows.Price" class="form-control font-weight-bold" id="PriceText" name="PriceText" type="text" readonly />
            <span asp-validation-for="Rows.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="Rows.Subtract" class="form-control text-danger font-weight-bold" value="0" id="SubtractX" name="SubtractX" type="text" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Rows.Subtract" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="Rows.Sum" class="form-control text-success font-weight-bold" id="SumX" name="SumX" type="number" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Rows.Sum" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
            <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-secondary ">Back</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Better to do it in C# if going for asp stuff. If you do client side page modifications via javascript, you earn cross side forgery errors due to the asp framework.
Read beginner asp tutorials to get an idea how server side pages do interact with C# classes.

Comment: How can i do this in C#? Can you provide a specific page link?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo(when dropdown change or input change or leaving an input field,it will calculate):

ViewBag.Price:

```
ViewBag.Price = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "100", Value = "1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "200", Value = "2" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "300", Value = "3" } };
```

View:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Rows.Qty" class="form-control" value="1" onblur="getSum()"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Rows.Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Price" id="ReadPrice" name="ReadPrice">
        </select>
        <input asp-for="Rows.Price" class="form-control font-weight-bold" id="PriceText" name="PriceText" type="text" readonly />
        <span asp-validation-for="Rows.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Rows.Subtract" class="form-control text-danger font-weight-bold" value="0" id="SubtractX" name="SubtractX" type="text" onblur="getSum()"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Rows.Subtract" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Rows.Sum" class="form-control text-success font-weight-bold" id="SumX" name="SumX" type="number" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Rows.Sum" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
        <a class="btn btn-secondary ">Back</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

js:

```
 @section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $("#PriceText").val($("#ReadPrice").find("option:selected").text());
            getSum();
        })
        $("#ReadPrice").change(function () {

            $("#PriceText").val($("#ReadPrice").find("option:selected").text());
            getSum();
        })
        function getSum() {
            var sum = parseInt($("#Rows_Qty").val()) * parseInt($("#PriceText").val()) - parseInt($("#SubtractX").val())
            $("#SumX").val(sum);
        }
    </script>
    
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: The dropdownlist that i use, reads the PriceName (not the id) directly from the Sql database, it is not static. How can i change the script to make it work?  ViewData["Price"] = new SelectList(_context.Prices, "PriceId", "PriceName");

Comment: What do you mean?You mean you need to read text of selected item rather than value of it?My demo is just use simple data to test.

Comment: Can you show your data of `new SelectList(_context.Prices, "PriceId", "PriceName");`?And why you use ViewBag.Price in your code,and you said you use ViewData["Price"] in comment?

Comment: The page is created in automatic from "Razor Pages Using EntityFramework CRUD".  The Create.cshtml.cs is :           [BindProperty]
        public Prices Price { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
                ViewData["DheId"] = new SelectList(_context.Prices, "PriceId", "PriceName");
                return Page();
        }

Comment: I know,I don't have the dbcontext of you,so I use a  sample selectlist.When you use `<select class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Price" id="ReadPrice" name="ReadPrice" >
            </select>`,you will bind `PriceId` to value,`PriceName` to Text.`$("#ReadPrice").val()` will get the selected value(PriceId).So what you want?

Comment: Picture link of what i get now : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dybw_5oRnDOBDUKc8qWX4If03_Vg4W-C/view?usp=sharing         What i want is this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_pViwbd8A0uU4-MbpJTf5RTvrilk3uFM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So you want to get text of selected option?Refer to my updated demo,use `$("#PriceText").val($("#ReadPrice").find("option:selected").text());`,and it can work.

Comment: It works but if i change the subtract value after the selection it doesn't recalculate the sum.

Comment: Have you used  `onblur="getSum()"` in `<input asp-for="Rows.Subtract" class="form-control text-danger font-weight-bold" value="0" id="SubtractX" name="SubtractX" type="text" onblur="getSum()"/>` as my answer shown?

Comment: I tried it now and it works. The database accepts the #PriceText only as integer, otherwise it doesn't permit saving the data. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me :**
Thank you "Yiyi You"

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#PriceText").val($("#ReadPrice").find("option:selected").text());
        getSum();
    })
    $("#ReadPrice").change(function () {

        $("#PriceText").val($("#ReadPrice").find("option:selected").text());
        getSum();
    })
    function getSum() {
        var sum = parseInt($("#Rows_Qty").val()) * parseInt($("#PriceText").val()) - parseInt($("#SubtractX").val())
        $("#SumX").val(sum);
    }
</script>


<script>
    $(function () {
        getSum();
    })
    $("#SubtractX").keyup(function () {
        getSum();
    })
    function getSum() {
        var sum = parseInt($("#Rows_Qty").val()) * parseInt($("#PriceText").val()) - parseInt($("#SubtractX").val())
        $("#SumX").val(sum);
    }
</script>
```